# Change eventListener function parameters based on iterator. (Vanilla JS)

Tags: javascript

What I want:
I have a method which takes an int as as its only parameter, then I'm creating a list where each element will call the other function when clicked, the only thing I want to change is the number that each element passes when clicked.

What I have:

```
while(++i<e){
    (...)
    a.addEventListener('click',function(){selectUser(i)},false);
    (...)
}
```

Of course, the obvious problem is that when called, it will always pass the final value of 'i'. 
I need that each element passes the value that 'i' had when it was created.
ie; when i=3, I want it to translate into:

```
a.addEventListener('click',function(){selectUser(3)},false);
```

I guess it involves some method which returns another method with the actual value, but I'm not really sure how to implement it. I have very little experience with js.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a classic problem of closures. You must enclose your event handler inside a closure function which keeps the state of your variable i. Like this...

```
while(++i<e){
    (...)
    (function(index){
    a.addEventListener('click',function(){selectUser(index)},false);
    })(i);
    (...)
}
```

This way every call of the wrapping function will keep your state of the variable i and thereby giving you the right result.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a new function scope. You could do it the following way (call an anonymous function, which in turn returns a new function with the specified `i`.

```
a.addEventListener('click',(function(index) {
    return function(){ selectUser(index) };
})(i),false);
```